# Docker compose with Nginx page refresh gives 404

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to serve up  a  front-end (vue.js) a back-end and a nginx reverse-proxy.

When I navigate to a route and hit refresh I get a 404 nginx error.

Here is part of my docker compose, omitted a few lines for brevity

```
version: '3'

services:

  # Proxies requests to internal services
  dc-reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:1.17.10
    container_name: reverse_proxy_demo
    depends_on:
        - dc-front-end
        - dc-back-end
    volumes:
      - ./reverse_proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 5004:80

  
  dc-front-end:
    ..
    container_name: dc-front-end
    ports:
      - 8080:80
  

  # API
  dc-back-end:
    container_name: dc-back-end
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
```

here is the nginx.conf that belongs to the reverse proxy service

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
         server {
            listen 80;
            server_name 127.0.0.1;

            location / {
                proxy_pass          http://dc-front-end:80;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }

            location /dc-back-end/ {
                proxy_pass          http://dc-back-end:5001/;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
        }
      
}
```

and this is the nginx.conf for the front-end

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include            /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main   '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                       '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log         /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile           on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root   /app;
        #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            index  index.html;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the docker file for the front-end service

```
# build stage
FROM node:16-alpine3.12 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I have tried using `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` in both nginx files but it still  gives 404 on page refresh or if i try and navigate to the page in the browser (rather than clicking a link)

Comment: Hi the problem is likely that your frontend has or has not some subfolders, I’ve would check the `dist` folder and align nginx conf accordingly, there is prolly a build flag that transforms build to SPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual the laws of Stackoverflow dictate that you only solve your own question once you post the question.

docker file was wrong. threw me as everything else worked

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.12 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```